# Problems when using variables with awk in shell scripts

Tags: shell

I am trying to code the simple shell scripts in a automatic way.
Parsing my string and concatenating the parsed string into original file context.

However, when I did it by using awk command, it didn't work although I identified the string I looked for was parsed well.

Below is my code.

```
for file in ./*.txt
do
    fileName="$( string $file | rev | cut -d. -f2 | rev)"
    echo $fileName
    awk '{print($2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t""0""\t""0""\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$fileName)}' $file
done
```

Can you give some tips?

Comment: `awk '{print $2, $3}' OFS='\t'` is a lot easier to read than `awk '{print $2"\t"$3}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you are just trying to reference the shell variable $filename.  One choice is to change quote styles (begin with single quotes, and end with double quotes) and use:

```
awk '{print $2, $3, $4, "0", "0", $5, $6, $7, $8, "'"$fileName\" }" OFS=\\t $file
```

You need to have double quotes around $fileName so that the shell interpolates it as a variable.  You can use double quotes on the whole thing and write `awk "{print \$2, ...` as well.  There a many ways to do the necessary quoting, but it is far more readable to pass the shell variable in as an awk variable:

```
awk '{print $2, $3, $4, "0", "0", $5, $6, $7, $8, f }' OFS=\\t f="$fileName" $file
```

Comment: Thanks. Your comments are really helpful in using shell scripts.